# Ajax cross-domain error, but I am using the same domain (CORS)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I just started reading a book about ajax. I'm setting up a testing environment to run the code over the network to test the examples as should be, since we're talking Ajax. I've already known Ajax cross-domain issue, but why am I getting this cross-domain error?

the url of the page that is requesting the resource is that:
http://diegodesignertest.freeiz.com/teste2.php (url I typed  in my browser)

the request is performed this way:
xhr.open("get", "http://diegodesignertest.freeiz.com/response.php", true);
 this code is contained in teste2.php and is requesting a response.php file (this make no sense I was just testing)

isn't the same domain?

Comment: The file doesn't exist, so your request will be redirected to an external 404 file from your webhoster. That's why you have this cross-domain error. Make use of the browser developer tools.

Comment: the response.php file does exist.

Comment: Apparently not. Since your webserver returns HTTP 404 Not Found.

Comment: The url in your code is wrong, if you posted your code someone would have immediately seen it.

Answer (score 0):

I've created an xml file and worked. The problem was the request of a php file.

didn't work
I changed the xhr.open("get", "http://diegodesignertest.freeiz.com/response.php", true);

worked
I changed the xhr.open("get", "http://diegodesignertest.freeiz.com/response.xml", true);